# How do I read and save a file into a 2D Array?

Tags: java, file, char, 2d

I want to read and save the content of the file in a 2d array, but I don't know the size of the file, because the program should read different files. So there is the first problem after "new char". I searched for the problem and found that "matrix[x][y]=zeile.charAt(x);"
should be right, but that throws the error "NullPointerException" when I write any number into the first brackets of new char.
Could somebody explain and give some ideas oder solutions? Thank you :)

```
import java.io.*;

class Unbenannt
{
  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
  {
    FileReader fr = new FileReader("Level4.txt");
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);

    String zeile = br.readLine();
    char [][] matrix = new char [][];

    while(zeile != null )
    {
      int y = 0;
      for(int x = 0; x < zeile.length(); x++) {
          matrix[x][y] = zeile.charAt(x);
       }
       y++;
    } System.out.print(matrix);
    br.close(); 
   }
}
```

Comment: your code is creating an infinite loop as you are not reading `zeile` from `br` anywhere in your loop.

Comment: Your initialization of `matrix` is invalid you have to put capacity while initializing an array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Arrays are stored as blocks in memory in order to achieve O(1) operations, which is why you need to define their size during definition. If you insist on arrays (rather than a dynamic ADT such as `List`), you'll need to know the dimensions in advance.

What you could do is store the file lines temporarily in a list and find out the maximum line length, i.e.:

```
List<String> lines = new ArrayList<String>();
String zeile = null;
int max = 0;

while ((zeile = br.readLine()) != null) {
   lines.add(zeile);
   if (zeile.length() > max)
      max = zeile.length();
}

char[][] matrix = new char[lines.length()][max];

// populate the matrix:
for (int i = 0; i < lines.length(); i++) {
   String line = lines.get(i);
   for (int j = 0; j < line.length(); j++) {
       matrix[i][j] = line.charAt(j);
   }
}
```

Note that since `char` is a primitive, you'll be initialized with the default value 0 (the integer, not the character!) in every cell of the inner array, so for lines which are shorter than the others, you'll have trailing zero characters.

Answer (score 0):

you initialize the matrix (char [][]) but you never initialize any of the inbound arrays. This leads to the NullPointerException.

In addition your 'while' condition looks invalid, seems you only are reading the first line of your file here > your code will never complete and read the first line over and over again

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all! It works! But there is still one problem. I changed lines.length() into lines.size(), because it doesn't work with length. The problem is the output.  It shows for example: xxxx xxxx instead of                  "xxx" and "x x" and "xxx" among each other.
How can I build in a line break?
my programcode is:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;


class Unbenannt
{
  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
  {
    FileReader fr = new FileReader("Level4.txt");
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);

    ArrayList<String> lines = new ArrayList<String>();
    String zeile = null;
    int max = 0;
    while ((zeile = br.readLine()) != null) {
        lines.add(zeile);
        if (zeile.length() > max)
            max = zeile.length();
    }
    char [][] matrix = new char[lines.size()][max];

    for(int i = 0; i < lines.size(); i++) {
        String line = lines.get(i);
        for(int j = 0; j < line.length(); j++) {
            matrix[i][j] = line.charAt(j);
            System.out.print(matrix[i][j]);
        }   
    }
    br.close();
   }    
}
```